# CakePHP hasOne belongsTo relationship, edit/add same action

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Using CakePHP 2.3. I am creating an application in which there is a Users table and a Profiles table. The association is like this: User hasOne Profile / Profile belongsTo User.

However, I would not like Users to have access to add their profiles, as this may produce copies of their profiles. I want a single action that will edit the ONE profile that the User is allowed.

Is there a way to initiate the profile with user_id and id but all other fields empty when a user is added? That way the user will automatically have a profile associated on signup and all that is needed is the edit action to fill in the blank fields.

Also it would be much cleaner in CakePHP if I could somehow make the id and user_id in the profiles table the same number. Keep in mind I also need to restrict users to edit only their profiles.

No code for now, just wanted your opinions on strategy for doing this, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a profile on user creation, just do

```
//your code for user saving
if($this->User->save())
   $this->User->Profile->save(array('user_id'=>$this->User->id))
```

or a variation of that and tada, the blank profile is save.

In fact, if you are sure you *always* want to add a profile to the recently created user, you can do it in [afterSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave) of the User model.

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public function afterSave($created) {
        //make sure to do it on creation and not on update
        if ($created) {
            $this->Profile->save(array('user_id'=>$this->getLastInsertID());
        }
    }
}
```

But keep in mind, if you have validations set in your Profile model, this will trigger them. Let's say you have a column "job" in the Profile that requires to not be null, then some errors are going to appear. You can bypass that by adding the `on` option in the validation process

```
class Profile extends AppModel {
public $validate = array(
    'job' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'You have to have a job',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
                            'on' => 'update'
        )
    ),
            /* etc */
}
```

Other option is to simply... not do that :)
If you don't want a user to add profiles like crazy, you can "hardcode" it's user id to the profile. For example, let's say you have an add action in the profile controller

```
class ProfilesController extends AppController {

     public function add($user_id) {
         //lets assume you have the user id somewhere, maybe even get the logged session one

         if($this->request->is('post')) {
             //when you are saving, force the add (or edit) to be for the user_id, not anyone
             $this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $user_id;
             $this->Profile->save();
         }
     }
```

With a few ifs here and there, there's no need to create the blank profile just after the user creation. But it doesn't hurt either...

Personally I like the afterSave option if you're sure you want to add a blank profile in all user-creation cases. Less code in the controller, but you have to be more careful with your profiles validations.

Oh, and about the "same id and user_id" in profiles... don't do that. There's no need, really. With a simple find you get the user and its profile with no problems, let cake handle the foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great answer and exactly what I wanted